# difference between fetching page and file in serviceworker

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

```
    event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
            return response;
        }          
         //return fetch(event.reuqest, { credentials: 'include' });

        //event.respondWith(fetch(event.request, { credentials: 'include' }));
    }));
```

This is a common code for handling request via serviceworkers , if the url is in cache then return cache response or fetch it from server .
But my doubt is regarding the 2 commented lines , we need to use one of them for fetching the response .

My doubt is, when i use `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request, { credentials: 'include'` for fetching a page , i get the following error

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The fetch event has already been responded to.

But the page is finally rendered , definitely browser is finally fetching the response , but when i use sam for fetching an image , i get the same error and on top of that the image is not fetched .

if i use the second option that `return fetch(event.reuqest, { credentials: 'include' });` , then it works fine for both image as well as page.

I am not able to figure out what is the reason of that error , and also why it is behaving differently for file and page .

My another doubt is , do i actually need the credential parameter here ,i added it because most of the implementations i saw in web have used it,but what i have observed is that the request object already has a credential property with it , now it is not always

> include

sometime it is

> same-origin

too.
So could it happen that i am actually overriding the actual credential value by adding it .If that is not the case , then there is no difference in including it or not.It does not matter .

But if it is other way around , then we should not overwrite the credential value, which can have bad side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a call to `event.respondWith`, you don't need to call it twice.

Your first call is going to use the promise returned by:

```
caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
  if (response) {
    return response;
  }

  return fetch(event.reuqest, { credentials: 'include' });
})
```

This promise resolves to:

- `response`, if the request is in the cache;
- the promise returned by the call to `fetch`, otherwise.

The promise returned by `fetch` will resolve to a response, which is then going to be used by respondWith.

Comment: Yeah but why is it  behaving differently for page and image file ?

Comment: Yeah i also think this is the correct syntax but why is it  behaving differently for page and image file in case when i use event.respondWith?                                                                        And also am i correct about the credential parameter ?  will it overwrite the existing credential value of event.request ?

Comment: For the first question, I don't know why it behaves differently for images vs pages. For the second question, yes, it will overwrite the existing credentials value (according to https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request, the new created request takes the `credentials` from the request object [step 7] and is overwritten later [step 18-19]).